# ModuleNotFoundError when importing subpackage using parent package name

Tags: python, python-import

I am trying to model an established Python project based on the recommendeded project structure according to https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/structure/.

After switching to this new structure, I now need to run the script with `$ python3 -m sample.runner` instead of just `$ python3 runner.py` or else I get a `ModuleNotFoundError`. I am trying to understand why that is and whether or not it can be avoided?

Runnning `$ python3 runner.py` with the new structure gives me:

```
$ python3 runner.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "runner.py", line 1, in <module>
    from sample.subpkg1 import subpkg1_file1 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sample'
```

Old project structure:

```
repo_root:
 | 
 |  |
 | ./subpkg1:
 |  | __init__.py
 |  | subpkg1_file1.py
 |  |
 | ./test:
 |  | __init__.py
 |  | bar.py
 |  |
 | runner.py
 | .coveragerc
 | README.md
 | tox.ini
 |
```

The new project structure:

```
repo_root:
 | 
 | ./sample:
 |  | __init__.py
 |  | runner.py
 |  |
 |  | ./subpkg1:
 |  |  | __init__.py
 |  |  | subpkg1_file1.py
 |  |
 | ./test:
 |  | __init__.py
 |  | bar.py
 |  |
 | .coveragerc
 | README.md
 | tox.ini
 |
```

I updated an import in runner.py with `sample` to satisfy tox tests. Without it, running tests with tox fails with a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'subpkg1'` message. My guess is that is because I am running tox from the repo_root, but I don't know that for sure.

**runner.py**

```
from sample.subpkg1 import subpkg1_file1 

def main():
    subpkg1_file1.print_subpkg1()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**subpkg1_file1.py** (though this shouldn't matter):

```
def print_subpkg1():

    print("Printing from subpkg1!")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `sample` module is not know because Python does not know where to look for it; it is not in PYTHONPATH. You can extend it at the beginning of the script if needed:

````py
import sys
if 'sample' not in sys.modules:
    from os import path as osp
    sys.path.insert(0, osp.dirname(osp.dirname(__file__)))
del os, sys

from sample.subpkg1 import subpkg1_file1 

def main():
    subpkg1_file1.print_subpkg1()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

```
````

Comment: OK, I think that make sense then of why running this with `$ python -m` would work.  According to the docs at https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m, "As with the -c option, the current directory will be added to the start of sys.path."

It seems strange to me that this project structure would be recommended without discussing these side-effects.